# Multi source, single sink network streaming with pipewire

Tags: linux, audio-streaming, pipewire

I have multiple linux computers on lan, all linux with pipewire installed. Only one of them have speakers hooked up to them. I want all computers to use this set of speakers - hence multiple source, single sink. I do not care about mic input, only audio output.

I have identified two pipewire modules that provide low latency streaming netjack2 and vban (ref: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Network), but documentation is sparse.

- VBAN: recv module requires specifying a source ip. Seems to imply
  that the connection is 1-1. Is this correct?
- netjack2: The manager/driver thing is confusing. I found a guide (https://github-wiki-see.page/m/jackaudio/jackaudio.github.com/wiki/WalkThrough_User_NetJack2), but it does not seem to deal with system audio. Can this work for my use case?

Will either work for my use case?
Is there a forum or discord to ask questions about pipewire? (other than stackoverflow ofcourse)